# How to convert ".." in path names to absolute name in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

How to convert the `..` in the path names to absolute path names in a bash script. That is, if I have a path `/home/nohsib/dvc/../bop`, I want this to be changed to the path without dots in it, in this case `/home/nohsib/bop`

How can I do that?

Comment: @Tony: Re. your mod: `'..'` is not an ellipsis. It's just two dots... One dot means the current directory, and two dots means the parent. An ellipsis indicates an indeterminate range. `'..'` is very specific.  [Ellipsis (programming operator)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28programming_operator%29)

Comment: @fred - Thanks, not sure what I was thinking there. All I can say is it's late, too late to be editing SO questions. Am off to bed.

Comment: This probably belongs on the Unix stack exchange site...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What you're looking for is **[`readlink`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/readlink-invocation.html)**:

```
absolute_path=$(readlink -m /home/nohsib/dvc/../bop)
```

*Please note:* You need to use GNU's `readlink` implementation which offers the "-m" option. BSD's `readlink` for example does not.

Comment: Much nicer than the `cd; pwd` solutions.  It's worth noting that the relevant C function is `realpath(3)`.

Comment: This isn't 100% portable but should work on most linux systems

Comment: This is incorrect answer. SO does not need to resolve symlink to real path, but expand relative path to absolute, which are different things. Suppose i have data files and symlink to script in a directory, if you want to resolve the absolute path of the dir when relative path to the symlink is used, so that i want to access the data files, readlink or realpath will fail

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Works on OSX as well, *if you use GNU's readlink. (You can get it e.g. via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/).)

Comment: The man page for 'readlink' includes "realpath(1) is the preferred command to use for canonicalization functionality."

Answer (score 45):

Try:

```
ABSOLUTE_PATH=$(cd /home/nohsib/dvc/../bop; pwd)
```

Comment: I think this answer should be at the top. It works. And it is cross-platform, unlike the readlink solutions which have problems on OS X.

Comment: @Craig:  `ABSOLUTE_PATH=$(cd $(dirname {dir or file}); pwd)`

Comment: @David: dirname <directory> gives a parent directory. You want `ABSOLUTE_PATH=$(cd $RELPATH 2>/dev/null || cd $(dirname $RELPATH); pwd)`

Answer (score 16):

One issue with using :

`ABSOLUTE_PATH=$(cd ${possibleDirectory}; pwd)`

is that if ${possibleDirectory} doesn't exist, ABSOLUTE_PATH will then be set to the current directory. Which is probably NOT what you want or expect.

I think using this version may be more desirable in general:

`ABSOLUTE_PATH=$(cd ${possibleDirectory} && pwd)`

If ${possibleDirectory} does not exist or is not accessible, due to missing directory access permissions, ABSOLUTE_PATH will contain the empty string.

The advantage of this is that you can then test for the empty string or let it fail naturally, depending on the circumstances. Defaulting to the current directory in the case of a failed 'cd' command may lead to very unexpected and possibly disastrous results (e.g. rm -rf "$ABSOLUTE_PATH" )

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do it without following any symlinks, then try using [`realpath`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) with option `-s`:

```
$ realpath -s /home/nohsib/dvc/../bop
/home/nohsib/bop
```

Note that with `realpath`, normally all but the last component must exist. So for the above to work, the following must all be present in the file system:

```
/home
/home/nohsib
/home/nohsib/dvc
```

But you can bypass that requirement using the `-m` option.

```
$ realpath -sm /home/nohsib/dvc/../bop
/home/nohsib/bop
```

(Note `realpath` is not available on all systems, especially older non-Debian systems. For those working on embedded Linux, unfortunately Busybox `realpath` doesn't support the `-s` or `-m` switches.)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
echo Absolute path: $(cd $1; pwd)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional note, if your current path is under a symlink, you can resolve the true path with this:

```
pwd -P
```

To solve your specific problem, this will issue a `cd` command to change directory to the path without the '..' in it.  Note you will be in the same folder, just with the correct path:

```
cd `pwd -P`
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to GNU's readlink and realpath, I had created functions as well that would run in scripts independent of external commands like pwd and stuffs.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/konsolebox-210384/getting-absolute-paths-of-unix-directories-and-filenames-in-shell-scripts-3956/

One of those is this one. It will save the absolute path to $__. I used read there to be safe from pathname expansion.

```
function getabspath {
    local -a T1 T2
    local -i I=0
    local IFS=/ A

    case "$1" in
    /*)
        read -r -a T1 <<< "$1"
        ;;
    *)
        read -r -a T1 <<< "/$PWD/$1"
        ;;
    esac

    T2=()

    for A in "${T1[@]}"; do
        case "$A" in
        ..)
            [[ I -ne 0 ]] && unset T2\[--I\]
            continue
            ;;
        .|'')
            continue
            ;;
        esac

        T2[I++]=$A
    done

    case "$1" in
    */)
        [[ I -ne 0 ]] && __="/${T2[*]}/" || __=/
        ;;
    *)
        [[ I -ne 0 ]] && __="/${T2[*]}" || __=/.
        ;;
    esac
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one good solution under a shell would be :

```
readlink -ev mypathname
```

It prints out the full path name with dots resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths must be converted into absolute, it is NOT required to exist!

Neither symlinks should be resolved.

Try this one-line python solution:

```
abs_path=$(python -c "import os; print(os.path.abspath(\"$rel_path\"))")
```

in your example:

```
python -c "import os; print(os.path.abspath(\"/home/nohsib/dvc/../bop\"))"
```

returns `/home/nohsib/bop`

Comment: also `normpath()` will work for non-absolute use-cases, eg  `some/kind/of/path/../../another/path` (and paths do not need to exist)

Answer (score -1):

Try this (assuming your relative path is stored in the variable $rel_path):

```
echo "`cd $rel_path; pwd`"
```

Comment: You execute pwd, capture its output, then use echo to print it?  No thanks, just run pwd without the backticks and without the echo (which cancel each other out, basically).