# Dots in Linux output

Tags: linux, bash

I am receiving an error from an application I am running

The error looks like this: [image]

I am curious what the dots mean in /usr/local/bin/../../etc/

Is this a shortcut I can use for something when writing a bash script?

I know this is probably a Linux noob question...

Comment: This is better asked on the Unix stack exchange site.

Comment: Two dots in a Unix path mean "parent directory". From the output of your program, it just looks like a program error... In effet, the message says that it is looking for path `/usr/etc/yarbu/conf/default/...` -- report a bug to the developer and/or package maintainer.

Comment: @J.Polfer you might be right. I just posted this after reading: and assumed they were similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643853/how-to-convert-in-path-names-to-absolute-name-in-a-bash-script

Comment: @John - Good point.  I dunno.  It's going to stay available for reading anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /usr/local/bin/../../etc/yarbu/conf/default
```

Is simply

```
cd /usr/etc/yarbu/conf/default
```

And that directory doesn't exist. It's likely located in `/etc/yarbu/conf/default` which is why it doesn't find it in `/usr/etc...`

`..` is the shortcut for parent directory and `.` is the shortcut for current directory.

Comment: You dropped out the `bin/`. It results in `/usr/etc/yarbu/...` when it is probably supposed to result in `/etc/yarbu/...`

Answer (score 0):

Well...

```
. means same directory
.. means parent directory
~ means home
/ means root
```

So,

```
/usr/local/bin/../../etc/yarbu/conf/default
```

is the same as,

```
/usr/etc/yarbu/conf/default
```

Comment: You also dropped out the `bin/`. It results in `/usr/etc/yarbu/...` when it is probably supposed to result in `/etc/yarbu/...`