# shell print effective directory - strip dots

Tags: shell, path, directory, editing

I'm seeking for a shell builtin or a shell command that "calculates" the effective directory path when a path looks like

```
TOMCAT_HOME=/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/../..
```

Result is obviously

```
/var/lib/tomcat7
```

I did a

```
pushd dirname $0
cd ${TOMCAT_HOME}
pwd
popd
```

which gives me what I want but there must be an easier way,  I can't think of it right now

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643853/how-to-convert-in-path-names-to-absolute-name-in-a-bash-script?

Answer (score 0):

One of the utilities that does that is `realpath`

```
$ realpath /var/lib/gconf/defaults/../..
/var/lib
```

You may need to install it.  On Debian, `apt-get install realpath`.

Another one, part of coreutils, is `readlink` when used with the `-f` option:

```
$ readlink -f /var/lib/gconf/defaults/../..
/var/lib
```

Comment: Or you could also use the standard utility `readlink`, without needing to install anything.

Comment: Thanks, but my intent was to use sheer shell builtins or "standard" commands.

Comment: @Krischu What OS are you on?  `readlink` is part of coreutils which make its quite standard.

Comment: my comment was aimed at your post (before you edited it again and added readlink). Before that there was only "realpath" and rwzy suggested readlink. :) But thanks to both.

Comment: @Krischu Sorry for the confusion.  I was editing in `readlink` at the same time that you and rwzy were commenting.

Comment: OK. No problem. Just to answer the open point: OS is Ubuntu 14.04. And readlink is fine. Solved it using readlink.